# Preferences with Fragments and ViewPagers - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, preferences

Got myself thoroughly confused with loads of SO tabs open that look related but don't quite answer my question so finally I admit defeat and ask my own.

I want to implement a settings page. I'm using fragments and a ViewPager as I have two main screens running under the same title and Actionbar (Encode and Decode screens). Here's snippets of my code (tried to take out the bits that seem irrelevant)

MainActivity.java

```
package uk.ac.ox.bras2756.colourgrid;

import android.app.ActionBar; ...etc

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager; ...etc

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected / Selected / Reselected ...etc

    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:...etc
            }
        }

    public static class LaunchpadSectionFragmentEncode extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_encode, container, false);
            ...return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class LaunchpadSectionFragmentDecode extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_decode, container, false);
            ...return rootView;
        }
    }

        @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SetPreferenceActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
          return(true);
      }

      return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

PrefsFragment.java

```
package uk.ac.ox.bras2756.colourgrid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.util.Log;

public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

SetPreferenceActivity.java

```
package uk.ac.ox.bras2756.colourgrid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SetPreferenceActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("SetPrefs", "Got there");

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefsFragment()).commit();
    }

}
```

res\xml\preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="prefkey_error"
            android:summary="@string/pref_sum_error"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_error"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/pref_decode"
        android:key="prefkey_decode">
        <ListPreference
            android:key="prefkey_matrix"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_matrix"
            android:summary="@string/pref_sum_matrix"
            android:entries="@array/matrixArray"
            android:entryValues="@array/matrixArrayValues" />
        <ListPreference
            android:key="prefkey_rotate"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_rotate"
            android:summary="@string/pref_sum_rotate"
            android:entries="@array/rotateArray"
            android:entryValues="@array/rotateArrayValues" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="prefkey_weight"
            android:summary="@string/pref_sum_weight"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_weight"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
        <ListPreference
            android:key="prefkey_colour"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_colour"
            android:entries="@array/colourArray"
            android:entryValues="@array/colourArrayValues" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/pref_camera"
        android:key="prefkey_camera">
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="prefkey_hotspots"
                android:title="@string/pref_title_hotspots"
                android:defaultValue="true" />
     </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

My app loads fine, but of course because something is missing the options button doesn't show up. What am I missing? I'll be checking here constantly until I can work this out - on a tight schedule!

Also, for some reason my preferences file always has the * next to it denoting it isn't saved, and when I run the app onto my phone it always asks me to save it first despite saving it manually. Not sure what's going on there!

Let me know if you need to see any more code, tried to just put up what was needed but I wasn't 100% sure.

EDIT:
All sorted. Updated my code above in case it can help anyone else.

Comment: "I want to add the three dots preferences button on the actionbar that everyone has these days" -- if you mean the action bar overflow, that "three dots button" will only be on devices that lack a dedicated MENU button: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html Also, if this is indeed what you are referring to, please post the code where you are configuring your action bar (e.g., `onCreateOptionsMenu()`).

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong to look for three dots, I just want my preferences page to be clickable somewhere so that I can let the user pick the options that app works with, using the menu button is fine by me. Also, I don't have the onCreateOptionsMenu anywhere yet, I'm confused where to put it and what to put inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, I don't have the onCreateOptionsMenu anywhere yet, I'm confused where to put it and what to put inside it.

The "three dots button" has nothing strictly to do with preferences. That is the action bar overflow (as seen on devices lacking a MENU button). You need to write some code, and usually an XML resource, to get something to appear in the action bar overflow, such as an item to go link to your `PreferenceActivity`.

For example, you might have a `res/menu/actions.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/settings" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences" android:title="@string/settings" android:showAsAction="never"></item>
</menu>
```

Your activity then could have:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.settings:
        // launch your PreferenceActivity here

        return(true);
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
  }
```

Where the comment indicates, you would call `startActivity()` on your `PreferenceActivity` that will use your `PreferenceFragment`.

You can read more about the action bar in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), and you can read more about `PreferenceActivity` in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll look into what you've suggested and come back.

Comment: I'm calling `new SetPreferenceActivity();` where you say "launch PreferenceActivity here" but having added a Log to the SetPreferenceActivity class I can see that we're never getting there in the code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @David: You do not start activities via the constructor. You start new activities via `startActivity()`: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivity

Comment: Who's a numpty? I am! I think I need to get some sleep - thanks for sticking around to point out the obvious. Got my settings screen now, much appreciated!

Comment: @David: "Who's a numpty?" *(quick searches Google for definition of "numpty")* well, me, more often than I like. Glad it's working for you now.

Comment: A couple of weeks ago I hadn't ever done any Java, Android or GUI. I'm still new enough to keep assuming that the problem involves something I haven't learnt yet only to slip up to some rather basic things periodically! Thank God for SO. Anyway, I've updated my code above in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: @David: "A couple of weeks ago I hadn't ever done any Java, Android or GUI" -- seriously? If so, you've made impressive strides. Congrats!

Comment: Yeah, it's a project for my Masters. I like coding but I've just done C, C++ and MATLAB before with a little javascript on the side. As an Engineer and not a Computer Scientist I'm expected to be able to code but I'm not taught. I'm also working with OpenCV which is causing my next current headache. Doing enough research to make sure I can't solve it on my own before I post another question. Nearly there though!